# c++ type error message from compiler, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm using g++ on fedora linux 13.
I'm just practicing some exercises from my c++ textbook
and can't get this one program to compile. Here is the code:

```
double *MovieData::calcMed() {
        double medianValue;
        double *medValPtr = &medianValue;
        *medValPtr = (sortArray[numStudents-1] / 2);
        return medValPtr;
}
```

Here is the class declaration:

```
    class MovieData 
{
private:
    int *students;                  // students points to int, will be dynamically allocated an array of integers.
    int **sortArray;                // A pointer that is pointing to an array of pointers.
    double average;                 // Average movies seen by students.
    double *median;                 // Median value of movies seen by students.
    int *mode;                  // Mode value, or most frequent number of movies seen by students.
    int numStudents;                // Number of students in sample.
    int totalMovies;                // Total number of movies seen by all students in the sample.
    double calcAvg();               // Method which calculates the average number of movies seen.
    double *calcMed();              // Method that calculates the mean value of data.
    int *calcMode();                // Method that calculates the mode of the data.
    int calcTotalMovies();              // Method that calculates the total amount of movies seen.
    void selectSort();              // Sort the Data using selection sort algorithm.
public:
    MovieData(int num, int movies[]);       // constructor
    ~MovieData();                   // destructor
    double getAvg() { return average; }     // returns the average
    double *getMed() { return median; } // returns the mean
    int *getMode()  { return mode; }        // returns the mode
    int getNumStudents() { return numStudents; }    // returns the number of students in sample
};
```

Here is my constructor and destructor and selectSort():

```
MovieData::MovieData(int num, int movies[]) {
    numStudents = num;

    // Now I will allocate memory for student and sortArray:
    if(num > 0) {
        students = new int[num];
        sortArray = new int*[num];

        // The arrays will now be initialized:
        for(int index = 0;index < numStudents;index++) {
            students[index] = movies[index];
            sortArray[index] = &students[index];
        }
        selectSort();   // sort the elements of sortArray[] that point to the elements of students.
        totalMovies = calcTotalMovies();
        average = calcAvg();
        median = calcMed();
        mode = calcMode();
    }
}

// Destructor:
// Delete the memory allocated in the constructor.
MovieData::~MovieData() {
    if(numStudents > 0) {
        delete [] students;
        students = 0;
        delete [] sortArray;
        sortArray = 0;
    }
}

// selectSort() 
// performs selection sort algorithm on sortArray[],
// an array of pointers.  Sorted on the values its 
// elements point to.
void MovieData::selectSort() {
    int scan, minIndex;
    int *minElement;

    for(scan = 0;scan < (numStudents - 1);scan++) {
        minIndex = scan;
        minElement = sortArray[scan];
        for(int index = 0;index < numStudents;index++) {
            if(*(sortArray[index]) < *minElement) {
                minElement = sortArray[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        sortArray[minIndex] = sortArray[scan];
        sortArray[scan] = minElement;
    }
}
```

The compiler is giving this error:

> moviedata.cpp: In memberfunction
>   'double * MovieData::calcMed()':
>
> moviedata.cpp:82: error: invalid
>   operands of types 'int*' and 'double'
>   to binary 'operator/'

I'm not sure what to make of this error, i've tried static casting the types with no luck, what does this error message mean?

Comment: From the look of it, sortArray is actually going to be a dynamically allocated array of pointers to integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortArray[numStudents - 1]` is a pointer to int, which can't be on the left side of a division (when you remember pointers are addresses, this makes sense).  If you post more of your code, we can help you correct it.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
int *MovieData::calcMed() {
      return sortArray[(numStudents - 1) / 2];
}
```

This returns the middle element in your array, which should be a pointer to the middle student.  I'm not clear why you're sorting lists of pointers (not the actual values), or why you're returning a pointer here.  The return value + 1 will be a pointer to the next value in `students`, which is *not* the next greater value numerically.  So you might as well return the actual student (int from `students`).  If you do this, you can also average the two middle elements when the count is even (this rule is part of the typical median algorithm).

Note that I changed the return type to `int *`, the type of sortArray's elements.  Also, your comment is incorrect.  This is the *median*, not the *mean*.

Also, your selection sort is wrong.  The inner loop should start at `scan + 1`.

Comment: which part of the code would be helpful, the class declaration?

Comment: Yes, and where `sortArray` is defined and initialized.

Comment: I added class declaration, constructor and destructor, and the selectSort() member function.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize that I even messed up on a comment, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Okay, that actually got it to compile, thanks! But I'd still like clarification on that compiler error: It's basically telling me that since my member function was returning a double*, I was trying to return a division between an int* and int? So I should really be returning a int*? Is that right?

Comment: so scan+1 should replace index? I'll take a closer look, I learned that from my textbook.  can you explain?

Comment: You can't divide any pointer by any value.  It just doesn't make sense, and isn't allowed.  The reason you should be returning an `int *` is that every element in sortArray is an `int *`.  If you decided to return the actual median, that would be an int.  Yes, `scan + 1` should replace `index`.  See this [psuedo-code](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/selectionSort.htm).  The reason is that you only want to swap with the smallest *later* element.  If you swap with an earlier element that is less, you're undoing your previous sorting work.

Comment: (numStudents - 1)/2 is not right - e.g. will return 1 when numStudents == 4. Technically to calculate the median correctly, you should use numStudents/2 for an odd number of students, and the average of the dereferenced values at numStudents/2 and at (numStudents-1)/2 for an even number of students.

Comment: @sje397, I added a note about that.  He would have to return an int, instead of a pointer into `students`.

Answer (score 3):

you are trying to divide a pointer by a double, which the compiler is saying it does not know how todo.

sortArray is probably defined by

int ** sortArray;

its also worth noting you are returning a pointer to a stack variable, who's value will be undefined as soon as you return out of the function.

Comment: what's a stack variable? pardon my ignorance.

Comment: The stack is a region of memory used by programming languages to keep track of function calls, function arguments, return values and temporary variables used within functions http://www.masters-of-the-void.com/book5.htm

Comment: Its also where the term 'stack overflow' is derived from. i.e. when the stack runs out of space and 'overflows' onto the heap or other regions of memory

Comment: Better links http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows a lack of understanding of pointers. You need to do more reading and practice on simpler examples.

More specifically:

`double medianValue;` creates a double variable. What for? You're apparently going to return a `double *` and returning a pointer to a local variable is **always wrong**, because local variables are "recycled" when their function ends.

`double *medValPtr = &medianValue;` creates a pointer called medValPtr and sets it to the location of medianValue. Well.

Due to the current contents of medValPtr, `*medValPtr = (sortArray[numStudents-1] / 2);` has the same effect as typing `medianValue = (sortArray[numStudents-1] / 2);` (supposing it were to compile at all).

Which it doesn't because `sortArray[numStudents-1]` is, at a guess, the last item in the array `sortArray` but happens to be a pointer to something else. You can't divide a pointer (numerically you can, but C++ disallows it's **always wrong**).

Finally you `return medValPtr;` which is **wrong** because `medValPtr` is pointing to a local variable.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to learn pointers and dynamic memory allocation.  I'm actually doing the exercises from my textbook on the pointers chapter. Are you trying to say that I should just have a return statement instead of all the other garbage?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
int *MovieData::calcMed() {
    return sortArray[numStudents/2];
}
```